# c# Array of single parameter functions each with a different type of param

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, generics, casting

This is really a 2 part question.

**1. How can an array of functions with different types for the parameters be stored in an Array or IEnumerable**

Is it possible to write code which would work like this:

```
Func<object, bool> fObj = (o) => false;
Func<Animal, bool> fAni = (a) => false;
Func<Cat, bool> fCat = (c) => true;
var funcArray = new Function1Array<bool>(fObj, fAni, fCat);
```

where `Function1Array<T>` takes something like `(params Func<?, T>[] funcs)`, even though c# doesn't allow generic WildCards

**2. Assuming question 1 can be done, could an object be checked to see if it is the same type as a param of one of the functions, and if so cast to the object**

*example:*

```
Cat myCat = new Cat();
funcArray.invokeFirstMatch(myCat); // Invokes fCat(myCat)

object myCat2 = new Cat();          // Declared as object instead of Cat
funcArray.invokeFirstMatch(myCat2); // Invokes fCat(myCat2)

Dog myDog = new Dog();
funcArray.invokeFirstMatch(myDog); // Invokes fObj(myDog)
```

---

My guess is that both questions are impossible without somehow wrapping each function since `Func<Cat, bool>` isn't a sub-type of `Func<object, bool>` which means there's no direct way to store an array of Functions in this manner.

Comment: What you want sounds like polymorphism.

Comment: @MikeBantegui, yes it's close but I updated the example in **#2** to show the difference. I want the correct function to run even when `myCat` is declared as an `object`.... I guess what I want is a more dynamic polymorphism that can be changed at runtime.

Comment: have you considered using the dlr?

Comment: @Tejas, correct me if I'm wrong, but DLR, is for importing functionality from a language other than the ones already supported by .Net, not for amending c# functionality.

Comment: @sparebytes: Is there a specific requirement that forces you to know the static type of the object?

Comment: no, you can use the DLR to achieve dynamic dispatch. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/curth/archive/2008/11/15/c-dynamic-and-multiple-dispatch.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
public class Function1Array<TOut> : IEnumerable
{
    private readonly List<Delegate> funcs = new List<Delegate>();

    public void Add<T>(Func<T, TOut> f)
    {
        this.funcs.Add(f);
    }

    public TOut InvokeFirstMatch<T>(T arg)
    {
        Delegate first = this.funcs.FirstOrDefault(d => d.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(T));
        if (first == null) throw new ArgumentException("No match");
        return ((Func<T, TOut>)first)(arg);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.funcs.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

which you can initialise with a collection initialiser:

```
var arr = new Function1Array<bool> { fObj, fAni, fCat };
```

Note that this requires the argument type to match exactly, although you could change the predicate given to `FirstOrDefault` to use `IsAssignableFrom`.

The generic parameter for `InvokeFirstMatch` means the search is done based on the static type of the argument. You can use the runtime type instead:

```
public TOut InvokeFirstMatch(object arg)
{
    var argType = arg.GetType();
    Delegate first = this.funcs.FirstOrDefault(d => d.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == argType);
    if (first == null) throw new ArgumentException("No match");
    return (TOut)first.DynamicInvoke(Convert.ChangeType(arg, argType));
}
```

Comment: To get it to work the way I expected I had to **(1)** remove the type parameter `<T>` from `InvokeFirstMatch` and instead do `Type T = arg.GetType();` and **(2)** change the return line to `(TOut)first.DynamicInvoke(Convert.ChangeType(arg, T));`

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it is technically what I asked for and it is the more powerful method, but all I really need is dynamic dispatch as @Tejas suggested in his comment.